# MySQL problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql, services

It randomly broke yesterday(not starting up any more) and I don't know how to fix it.

When I run:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

It gives this error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error 
code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of `systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)<br>
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-09-05 15:10:31 CEST; 43s ago<br>
  Process: 6515 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)<br>
Sep 05 15:10:31 vps310084 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.<br>
Sep 05 15:10:31 vps310084 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.<br>
Sep 05 15:10:31 vps310084 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.<br>
Sep 05 15:10:31 vps310084 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.<br>
Sep 05 15:10:33 vps310084 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.<br>
Sep 05 15:10:33 vps310084 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Output of `journalctl -xe`:

```
Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel**
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed. 
Sep 05 15:14:56 vps310084 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state. 
Sep 05 15:14:56 vps310084 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 05 15:14:56 vps310084 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart. 
Sep 05 15:14:56 vps310084 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down<br>
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down. 
Sep 05 15:14:56 vps310084 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly. 
Sep 05 15:14:56 vps310084 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

the systemctl startup script for Mysql is failing to run this command 
/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre

this doesn't do much other than sanity check your environment using the following shell code :

```
sanity () {
  if [ ! -r /etc/mysql/my.cnf ]; then
    echo "MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Please create one."
    exit 1
  fi

  if [ ! -d /var/lib/mysql ] && [ ! -L /var/lib/mysql ]; then
    echo "MySQL data dir not found at /var/lib/mysql. Please create one."
    exit 1
  fi

  if [ ! -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ] && [ ! -L /var/lib/mysql/mysql ]; then
    echo "MySQL system database not found. Please run mysql_install_db tool."
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

if you run it directly via sudo you should get one of those error messages , please follow its suggestions and try again untill it works.

This isn't a random breakage this is missing files , check the bash_history of the root user and any user who can sudo.

Comment: Alright, so it says: MySQL system database not found. Please run mysql_install_db tool. But how would the database be installed, when i changed nothing.

Comment: maybe your var partition failed to mount and so your /var dir is empty

Comment: Ah well, when i try to run the installation process again it says: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'.

Comment: Think about it , the server is not running .   Its not running because the data has been deleted or the storage containing it is not available to the system in the same way it was at install time.

Comment: is there a /var directory and does it have any folders in it ? i'm guessing it wont because it looks like your mount failed.

Comment: Yes there is a /var dir, its packed with stuff, but doesnt have a /mysql folder.

Comment: Alright so what would the solution be?

Comment: it needs a /var/lib/mysql folder , does it have one of those ?

Comment: the solution would be to restore from a backup the /var/lib/mysql folder.